# Connection String for a MS Access file?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, dataset

I added a MS Access file into a project and VS created me a DataSet. I was very happy with that, but now I've a small problem:

I want to have the connection string in the app.config file, to allow customer to edit it. I go to the app.config file and I saw this connection String, "GREAT" I thought.

But it seems that this is not used. I found that the connectionString which is used is contained into the Settings.settings file, which I cannot edit at run-time.

Any idea how to resolve this? I even can specify myself the connection string programmatically if needed, but I didn't find how to specify this.

Thank you very much!

EDIT: Here a some code:

One example of the generated code which seems to refer to the Settings.settings file:

```
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")]
        private void InitConnection() {
            this._connection = new global::System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
            this._connection.ConnectionString = global::Infoteam.CliniqueLaSource.DocuShare.Communication.DatabaseAccess.Properties.Settings.Default.ClsConnectionString;
        }
```

What I've in my app.config file:

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Infoteam.CliniqueLaSource.DocuShare.DatabaseAccess.Properties.Settings.ClsConnectionString"
        connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\Workspace\CliniqueLaSource.CLS-DocuShare\Main\Resources\Cls.mdb;Persist Security Info=True"
        providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

What I've in the Settings.settings file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="Infoteam.CliniqueLaSource.DocuShare.DatabaseAccess.Properties" GeneratedClassName="Settings">
  <Profiles />
  <Settings>
    <Setting Name="ClsConnectionString" Type="(Connection string)" Scope="Application">
      <DesignTimeValue Profile="(Default)">
        &lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?&gt;
        &lt;SerializableConnectionString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"&gt;
        &lt;ConnectionString&gt;Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Cls.mdb;Persist Security Info=True&lt;/ConnectionString&gt;
        &lt;ProviderName&gt;System.Data.OleDb&lt;/ProviderName&gt;
        &lt;/SerializableConnectionString&gt;
      </DesignTimeValue>
      <Value Profile="(Default)">Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Cls.mdb;Persist Security Info=True</Value>
    </Setting>
  </Settings>
</SettingsFile>
```

Here is a small example of the usage I'm doing:

```
    ClsDataSet dataSet = new ClsDataSet();
    DOCDOCUMENTSTableAdapter adapter = new DOCDOCUMENTSTableAdapter();
    adapter.Fill(dataSet.DOCDOCUMENTS);
    return dataSet.DOCDOCUMENTS.ToList();
```

Comment: Please show the code snippet from the config file that shows the connection string (and delete sensitive information from it if necessary).  The reason I ask is that there IS a relation between the .settings file and the .config file, and we may be able to explain better.  Also, if you can find in the code where you're saying that the .Settings string is used and not the .config string, that would help.

Comment: Is it not possible to remove the conn string from setting file then the one in app.config will be considered.

Programatically you can use 

        conn = new OleDbConnection(
            "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; " + 
            "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("Pets/Pets.mdb"));

Comment: @David: I added some code :)
@Rahul: No, it's not possible, if I do this, I've compilation error in the generated code, which doesn't find the connection string. Where in my code can I specify this connection? (and I'm not on a server, it's a simple client application

Comment: may be ... I was just curious. Anyways if you would like to specify the conn string in your code then take a look at this MSDN post for MS Access. It gives an example as well which will be of help. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971485.aspx

Comment: I took a look to your code, but it isn't using any DataSet automatically generated by visual studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When VS creates a strongly typed `DataSet` for you, it will also create strongly typed wrappers around `DataAdapters` to fill your `DataSet` and to update the database.

These strongly typed wrappers or `TableAdapters` can be configured to use any connection you want. Simply set the `Connection` property to a connection initialized with the connection string you wish and you are all set.

If setting the connection everytime you create a new `TableAdapter` is too cumbersome you can also take advantage of them being `partial` classes. This means you can add another code file that wont be overwritten everytime the DataSet designer tool updates the underlying code and overload the DataTable constructor so it takes a connection string or a connection instance and you set the property accordingly inside the constructor:

```
 public partial class MyTableTableAdapter
 {
     public MyTableTableAdapter(OleDbConnection connection)
     {
          if (connection == null)
              throw new ArgumentNullException("connection");

          base.Connection = connection;
     }

     public MyTableTableAdapter(string connectionString)
     {
          base.Connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
     }
}
```

If you have a lot of `TableAdapters` this might be a bore and your better off just setting the connection manually each time you instantiate a `TableAdapter`

Comment: I have an accessor which create every table adapter so I will directly use this! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps:  http://www.connectionstrings.com/

**EDIT**

Sorry, misread the first time through.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/PersistConnectionStrings.aspx

Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: That's not what he's asking for.

Comment: .... I think you didn't read my post... I know exactly what connection string I've to set, the problem is that I need to have it in my app.config file, and it uses the one in the Settings.settings file.

Comment: Yep I apologize, I misread and caught that after I posted this.

Comment: @Jeff Sheldon : nope, I want that the application use the connection string present in my app.config file(which has been created by visual studio). Because I can edit it without having a visual studio to rebuild it.

Comment: I understand that.  That code should allow you to change the settings connection string by doing:

My.Settings.SetUserOverride("ConnectionString1", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyAppConnString"))

Comment: Hum, okay, but I'm really not familiar with VB, do you know the equivalent in c#? I'm a little lost in the code with these Me/My properties